# Software Engineer and CyberSecurity expert simple and effective position title suggestion

Tags: salary, job-change, title, position

I am a Lead Software Application Engineer and now I am being asked to take care of the cyber security department as well, for which I recently did a cyber security expert certification.

I am trying to come up with a proper job title which covers both of the function but doesn't sound like two different job title. (unless its good to have two job titles)

also, I am not sure what should I be looking at in terms of the salary package.

PS. I suggested "Lead" to be added to my title, should have asked to add "principal" or chief.

Over to you guys.

Proposed title by HR: Lead Software application engineer and cybersecurity expert

I am have been researching about job titles that don't
 overstep CTO CIO roles title but 
should be specific to what I do as Head of the software architect and CyberSecurity department keeping my positions market value in mind < CTO
So far I got Enterprise Architect but it's very ambiguous, I am looking for something simple and short so I will have no problem in introducing myself.

Answer (score 2):

Lead Software Application and Security Engineer? (Keep it simple :) )

I think a jobtitle is just a title, explaining your responsibilities and tasks. It should indicate what your function is and how you are positioned in the company (e.g. the Lead part shows you have quite some responsibilities).

So just keep it easy and simple, I think too complicated or abstract jobtitles only cause confusion.

Comment: Perhaps "Lead Software Application and *Cyber* Security Engineer" if the distinction is important in this case.  Either way I agree with the theme of this answer.

Comment: "Lead Software Application Engineer and CyberSecurity Expert" This is was proposed to me. What do you guys think

Comment: @australianGrandDaddy Personally, I don't think the term "expert" is appropriate in a position title.  Engineer seems like a better term than "expert", as "expert" is vague and doesn't give any indication of your actual roles (I'd also be weary of personally calling myself an expert, since IMO it implies a level of extreme understanding that is next to impossible to actually accumulate in fields with broad interpretations).

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"One to avoid is Lead Software Application and Security Engineer. (Keeping it simple wouldn't be okay :) )"_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: I am have been reasearching about job titles that doesnt overstep my managers title but should be specific to what I do as Head of the software architect and cybersecurity department.